# How to store the list of subdirectories into an array and access them by their index in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

Assume That we have a directory name "A" with 4 sub directories(aa,bb,cc,dd), some of the sub directories also have sub directories, so assume a schematic like below:

```
  A
      aa
           aaa
      bb
           bbb
           bbbb
      cc
      dd
```

I tried to list the sub directories(`aa,bb,cc,dd`) in an array and then use them in my script by their array number.
I used the script below for copying `dd` to parent directory:

```
while IFS= read -d '' file; do
    A+=( "$file" )
done < <(find . -type d -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z)

cp -r  `pwd`/${A[4]}"  `pwd`/..
```

But the problem is that the script make an array of all of the sub-directories, `[aa aaa bb bbb bbbb cc dd]`
so `${a[4]} = bbb` and not `dd`.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: If you want to stop `find` at a given depth, you can use its `-maxdepth` (`-mindepth`) options: `find . -type d -maxdepth 2`.

Comment: See my answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict `find` to just look at the top directory, with the `maxdepth` option:

```
find . -type d -print0 -maxdepth 1 | LC_ALL=C sort -z
```

You can achieve the same thing in a simpler way using a glob:

```
dirs=(*/)             # store all top level directories into the dirs array
dirs=("${dirs[@]%/}") # strip trailing / from each element of the array
```

and then

```
cp -r  "$PWD/${dirs[4]}"  "$PWD/.."
```

- Double quotes are needed to prevent word splitting and globbing
- `pwd` in backquotes can simply be written as `$PWD`, which doesn't need to create a subshell

Comment: Nit: should be `dirs=("${dirs[@]%/}")` to avoid word splitting and glob expansion.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive response, I really appreciate it.